# resizing the image file by using an div

Tags: html

Is it possible to set the size of an image by defining the style for the div??
In this scenario we cant do anything to image tag directly since it's dynamically inserted to the page.

Comment: So you might be using JS/JQuery anywhere on page as talking about dynamic. Right?

Comment: No I'm using text editor to include it

Comment: I am not asking particular for this, i am asking is are you planning to use JS/JQuery for an answer?

Comment: oh ok.. No if it is pure html that will be great.. is that possible??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this:

Here the image inside a div having class `.img-box`, which has specific `width:250px` and `height:250px;`.

By giving `width:100%;`  and `height:100%;` to `img` image stretches to maximum available height and width of `div`.

The pink area you see here is the background for `div .img-box` and that's visible as i gave `padding:2px;` to it. If you want you can remove `padding` to fit in exactly without leaving any spaces.

**<kbd>[Working Demo : To Play around](http://jsfiddle.net/divy3993/3qq9s8g3/)</kbd>**

Check this out:

```css
body{margin:0px;}
.img-box
{
    margin:0px;
    height:250px;
    width:250px;
    background:pink;
    padding:2px;
    
}

.img-box img
{
    margin:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-box">
    <img src="http://www.mountainguides.com/photos/everest-south/c2_2011b.jpg" />
</div>
```